# Some weird transformation to pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

My dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':['A', 'B'], 'b':[{5:1, 11:2}, {5:3}]})
```

Expected output (Each Key will be transformed to 'n' keys. Example row 1, key =5 (with value =2) get transformed to 5, 6. This change also need to reflect on 'a' column)

```
df_expected = pd.DataFrame({'a':['A1', 'A2', 'A1', 'A2', 'B1', 'B2', 'B3'], 'key':[5, 6, 11, 12, 5, 6, 7]})
```

My present state:

```
df['key']=df.apply(lambda x: x['b'].keys(), axis=1)
df['value']=df.apply(lambda x: max(x['b'].values()), axis=1)
df = df.loc[df.index.repeat(df.value)]
```

Stuck here. What should be next step?

Expected output:

```
df_expected = pd.DataFrame({'a':['A1', 'A2', 'A1', 'A2', 'B1', 'B2', 'B3'], 'key':[5, 6, 11, 12, 5, 6, 7]})
```

Comment: As with many such tasks, it would be easier to transform your data BEFORE you shove it into pandas.  Is this a school assignment, or is this a practical issue?

Comment: Your text says "row 1 key=5 with value=2", but key 5 has the value 1.  Which is the typo?

Answer (score 0):

This will do your transform, outside of pandas.

```
d = {'a':['A', 'B'], 'b':[{5:1, 11:2}, {5:3}]}

out = { 'a':[], 'b':[] }
for a,b in zip(d['a'],d['b']):
    n = max(b.values())
    for k in b:
        for i in range(n):
            out['a'].append(f'{a}{i+1}')
            out['b'].append(k+i)
print(out)
```

Output:

```
{'a': ['A1', 'A2', 'A1', 'A2', 'B1', 'B2', 'B3'], 'b': [5, 6, 11, 12, 5, 6, 7]}
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to preprocess your input dictionary like this

```
import pandas as pd
d = {'a':['A', 'B'], 'b':[{5:2, 11:2}, {5:3}]} # Assuming 5:2 instead of 5:1.
res = {"a": [], "keys": []}
for idx, i in enumerate(d['b']):
    res['a'].extend([f"{d['a'][idx]}{k}" for j in i for k in range(1,i[j]+1) ])
    res['keys'].extend([k for j in i for k in range(j, j+i[j])])
df = pd.DataFrame(res)
```

**output**

```
{'a': ['A1', 'A2', 'A1', 'A2', 'B1', 'B2', 'B3'], 'keys': [5, 6, 11, 12, 5, 6, 7]}
```

Answer (score 0):

For a [pandas](/questions/tagged/pandas) solution:

```
df2 = (df.drop(columns='b')
       .join(pd.json_normalize(df['b'])
        .rename_axis(columns='key')
        .stack().reset_index(-1, name='repeat')
       )
   .loc[lambda d: d.index.repeat(d.pop('repeat'))]
 )

g = df2.groupby(['a', 'key']).cumcount()

df2['a'] += g.add(1).astype(str)
df2['key'] += g

print(df2)
```

Output:

```
    a  key
0  A1    5
0  A1   11
0  A2    6
0  A2   12
0  A3    7
0  A3   13
1  B1    5
1  B2    6
1  B3    7
```